# Update partial view wtih webgrid after delete a row ajax MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to update a webgrid which is being call in a partial view.

I load my partial view through Ajax.ActionLink

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "ShowAssistants", "Assistants", new { assistusername = item.AssistantUserName }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "add_research" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-link" })
```

In this partial view I have a webgrid in which one column has delete action method

```
 @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/Assistants/DeleteAssistant/" + item.ID + "' id='" + item.ID + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
```

I call a modal which just ask the user if wants to delete the row. After he press the yes button the record has been deleted but the partial view and webgrid is not updated.

ajax code

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $('#progress').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#progress').hide();
               //location.reload();

                $("#add_research").load('@Url.Action("ShowAssistants", "Assistants")');

            } else {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
  }
```

If I remove the 
  `$("#add_research").load('@Url.Action("ShowAssistants", "Assistants")');`

and leave the `location.reload();`

it refresh the page but the partial view is being disappeared which is normal. And the user has to click the  `Ajax.ActionLink` so to see the records again.
Any idea on how to kept the partial view in the page and to upgrade the webgrid?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use ajax load function like this and it loads partial view successfully:

```
$("#add_research").load('/Assistants/ShowAssistants');
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, now it shows only the headers of the webgrid no the rows with data.

Comment: Is it posssible the problem is based on your "ShowAssistants" function? Maybe you are missing something in there?

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I am getting error because of a viewbag in which I store the assistant name and it out of the webgrid. I am getting "Sequence contains no elements". This was working before. I am going to check it thank you.

Comment: Hello do you know how can I pass a value from ajax back to controller? It loose data after reload it. thank u!